# Radio Button with default selection in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I had the same doubt of radio button in model file.

I want it to be a compulsory/required field with default selection to "No".

Fields available would be - Yes/No. Any suggestions.

```
B_CHOICES = [('P','Positive'),('N','Negative')]
Tag_Type = models.CharField(choices=B_CHOICES, max_length=128)
```

Here's my form and model code-

Form -

```
<form id="ant_form" name="ant_form" method="POST" action="#">{% csrf_token %}

<input name="r_user" type="checkbox" value="{{user.id}}" />  {{user.username}}      

<input type="radio" name="txt{{user.id}}" value="P" > </input>      
    P Comment
<input type="radio" name="txt{{user.id}}" value="N" > </input>              
    N Comment

<textarea style="height: auto" rows="1" id="txt{{user.id}}" name="comment_{{user.id}}" cols="50">
</textarea>
<br>
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>

{% endif %} {# users #}

</form>
```

Model -

```
class r(models.Model):

BCHOICES = [('P','P'),('N','N'),] 

tag_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, default=Negative, choices=BCHOICES)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `default` to `'N'`:

```
from django.db import models

B_CHOICES = [('P','Positive'),('N','Negative')]

class MyModel(models.Model):
    tag_type = models.CharField(choices=B_CHOICES, max_length=128, default='N')
```

When you render a `ModelForm` for the given `MyModel`, then the HTML will look like:

```
<select name="tag_type" id="id_tag_type">
  <option value="P">Positive</option>
  <option value="N" selected>Negative</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @willem. I did try this one. But the issue with this is that, even if I select Y on radio button i.e. Yes, it enter N in the database which is incorrect. How should I correct that...

Comment: @ABB: what form did you use?

Comment: This is my form info - <form id="abc_form" name="abc_form" method="POST" action="#">

Comment: @ABB: I mean what *Django* form did you use to render the form, and process the request data.

Comment: Could you elaborate here, as I don't see info about forms. Some examples might help:)

Comment: Info of imports I made.   from django.db import models
    from main.models import Tk, Rp, Rs, Pc, Rv, Pt
    from main.wrapper import get, TemplateRp
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from django.core.validators import URLValidator
    from django.template.loader import get_template
    from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
    from cStringIO import StringIO

Comment: @ABB: see this article on using `ModelForm`s: https://www.journaldev.com/22467/django-modelforms

Comment: My Application uses Model class to create forms directly from database values Eg- class SampleModel(models.Model):

Comment: Is the any one that could help me here. This is bit urgent!

Comment: @ABB: can you share your current view/form/template/... that you are using. It looks like somewhere you did an override of the normal behavior. Please [`[edit]`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56407153/edit) your question.

Comment: I have updated the question, do let me know if anything else needs to be added.

Comment: @ABB: the view, but you should *not* construct the form yourself. Django can create a form...

Comment: I'm not understanding this, I have a similar case where I store text in database using the below code - Model - Textd = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True) - View - <textarea style="height: auto" rows="1" id="txt{{u.id}}" name="com_{{u.id}}" cols="50"> </textarea> This works well and stores the data in database but in case of radio button it doesn't...

Comment: @ABB: it is really not a good idea to do form construction yourself, since you make an "unstable" link between models/forms and templates. You should let the `ModelForm` render the form. Can you please share your `views.py`.

Comment: I don't have a view.py, instead I have specific views for specific activity. Note- class pwRev(Rev): class Meta: proxy = True This is the class that is available on the view page. Does this helps

Comment: @ABB: that is *not* a view, you really should define a view that basically makes the changes to the model. Otherwise you are violating Django's MVC pattern. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/views/

Comment: This is a long ago creation. I'm trying to update a module of it. Now, when i add t_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, default=Negative, choices=BCHOICES) it makes an entry in database as N which is not correct. It should take values from the selected option from the input. Is there are way we could manage this.